# Aligning polygons in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, topology, alignment

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

I am working on a map that I have divided into 5 zones. I have drawn 5 polygons to represent each zone. I need to align the polygons where the edges meet.  I am trying to use the "Align Edge" tool in the Topology toolbar. I select the tool, click an area of one polygon where there is a sliver I need to remove.  I see a dotted line and then click the other polygon where I want the edges to align.

I get an error message that reads:

> The edge cannot be modified. The operation was attempted on an empty
>   geometry.

I don't know why this is happening or how to rectify.

Comment: Try Integrate http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002s000000 but **back up your data first**, every time I talk about this tool I always emphasize that with *a tolerance that is carelessly large* will **destroy your data with no chance of return**.. now that the warning is out of the way it's a very handy tool for fixing sliver polygons but be aware that all data to be integrated will move to some degree. If you don't want the zone boundaries to move use Snap http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000007000000 instead.

Comment: Start again. Make big polygon and cut it. Alternatively draw one small and use auto complete polygon tool to draw next

Comment: Thanks so much.  Integrate is a fantastic find.  It did exactly what I needed. I did need to fix a few things, but the tool saved a ton of time. Felix, thanks for the advice about cutting the big polygon, next time I'll start differently.